# AndroidStudio commit changes not show other module git

Tags: git, android-studio-3.0

My Project- "MyAndroid"  dependencies another  git module - "rocket"

[image]

But  I cannot see  commit changes  if I change the rocket  file.  I can only see the file which in  MyAndroid  project .

[image]

But rocket foler shows  When  I want to  push .

[image]

Anyone know  how to  show  rocket  in the Commit Changes ?

Comment: Is `rocket` a formal Git submodule?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  No , I directly  clone from  the  git  repositories 。Then  I  add the dependencies  to  the  gradle

Comment: OK...are the `MyAndroid` and `Rocket` folders separate Git repos?  If they are, then maybe Android Studio would only focus on one repo at a time.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Yes, they are  separate Git repos !    Do you know  how  to  show  focus  them  at  a time ?

Comment: No...but I wouldn't attempt to do Git operations like this from Android Studio.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Thanks for your reply  anyway  .

Comment: @HarleyQuinn did you figure it out yet?

Comment: i face with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Commit changes with GitBash and restart Android. Worked for me.